# При комбинации <li class="menu__right__item1"><a href="" class="menu__right__item1__link1">Home</a></li> в CSS не хочет включатся ::before

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

```
<li class="menu__right__item1"><a href="" class="menu__right__item1__link1">Home</a></li>

CSS 
&__right{
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 43px;
        margin-bottom: 26px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        &__item1{
            
            &__link1{
                position: relative;
                left: 1px;
                ::before{
                    content: url(../img/home.png);
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 1px;
                    top: 1px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде `::before` будет вешаться на дочерний элемент `__link1`, а не на него самого. Чтобы это исправить, поставьте перед `::before` `&` - `&::before`.